# What is the difference between $\mathbf P()$ and $p()$?

Tags: probability

I am trying out the first probability problem at this [link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn04.pdf) which looks something like this:

[image: img]

I would like to ask what is the difference between $\mathbf P(...)$ and $p_{...}(...)$?  Aren't they both just probability?  Why bother using different symbols?  Thanks.

Comment: I think $p()$ is the joint density, whereas $\mathbf P()$ refers only to $Y$. Is just to distinguish them as we use $Y$ for the r.v. and $y$ for the particular realization.

Comment: In this case $p_{X,Y}(x,y) = \mathbf P(X=x, Y=y)$ so you might want to say they are equivalent.  Here $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ takes the form of a function of $x$ and $y$ while  $\mathbf P(X=x, Y=y)$ takes the form of the probability of an event, and you might want to draw that distinction.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathsf P(X=x)$ is the probability for the event of $X=x$.

$p_{\small X\!}(x)$ is the probability mass function of random variable $X$, measured at $x$.

Okay, yes, these are the same thing.

However, while we may generally measure the probability of *various* types of events, the probability mass function (pmf) of a random variable is something of special interest. So we have a special representation for it.

It describes the distribution of the random variable and can be used to derive various properties of the distribution.  The mean, the variance, et cetera.

[Also $p_{\small X\!}(x)$ takes up *slightly* less typesetting on the page than $\mathsf P(X=x)$ , so can save space in long formulae.]

Answer (score 0):

The probability of an event A is written as $P(A)$, $p(A)$, or $Pr(A)$.

I'm recommending on this answers for your question:

- [Upper case (P) or lower case (p) to denote p-values and probabilities in frequentist and Bayesian statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260711/upper-case-p-or-lower-case-p-to-denote-p-values-and-probabilities-in-frequen)
- [Which notation and why: P(), Pr(), Prob(), or P()](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108441/which-notation-and-why-textp-pr-textprob-or-mathbbp)